# Somar valores de uma coluna de uma entidade relacionada com Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, relacionamento

Estou tentando construir uma aplicação em Rails. Nela possuo um recurso onde o usuário cadastra produtos e vendas. O relacionamento é muito para muitos, para passar um array de produtos para vendas fiz da seguinte

```
def sale_params
    params.require(:sale).permit(:value, :client_id, :installments, product_ids: [])
end
```

Gostaria de um dica como faço para somar todos os preços dos produtos.
Eu fiz assim na view

```
  <tbody>
    <% @sales.each do |sale| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= sale.product.sum(:price) %></td>
      <td><%  sale.products.each do |product| %>
       <li> <%= link_to product.name, product_path(product)  %></li>
      <% end %></td>
      <%= sale.products.count %>
      <td><%= sale.client.name %></td>
      <td><%= sale.installments %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', sale %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_sale_path(sale) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', sale, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Funcionou mas não é legal colocar regra de negocio na view.
Outra coisa queria que quando fosse cadastrar esse valor fosse atualizado conforme vou selecionando os produtos para adicionar na venda, eu fiz assim, mas não funciona.

```
<%= form_for(@sale) do |f| %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :value %>
      <%= f.text_field :value, :value => @sale.products.sum(:price) %>
    </div>

   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :client_id %>
     <%= f.select :client_id, Client.all.collect {|c| [c.name, c.id]}, include_blank: true %>
  </div>

<br/>
    <%= f.label :products %>
    <% for product in Product.all %>
    <div >
      <%= check_box_tag "sale[product_ids][]", product.id, @sale.products.include?(product) %>
     <%= product.name %> -
     <%= product.price %>
   </div>
  <% end %>
<br/>

   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :installments %>
     <%= f.text_field :installments %>
   </div>


  <div class="row">
    <div class="span1 actions">
       <%= f.submit :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a proprio relacionamento para fazer a soma dos valores

```
sale.products.sum(:price)
```

Para tirar essas querys da view você tem que aprender usar o feilds_for

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

exemplo

```
<%= form_for(@sale) do |f| %>
#...

<div class="field">
  <%= f.collection_select(:city_id, options_for_select(Client.all, :id, :name)) %>
</div

  <%= f.fields_for :products do |product| %>
    <%= product.label :product %>
    <div >
    <%= product.collection_check_boxes :product_ids, Product.all, :id, product.name %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Complementando a resposta, para atualizar a soma dos valores do produtos, imagino que vc queira que atualize assim que o usuário selecione mais um produto pelos checkboxes. Sendo assim, você terá que usar Javascript para fazer isso. Caso você fique confuso com a distinção entre código Rails e Javascript (quando usar um, quando usar outro?), primeiro reflita sobre aonde a parada acontece. Se é do lado do servidor é Rails, se é no browser do usuário é Javascript. Essa distinção é muito importante para trabalhar bem com javascript, estude bem isso também.